# Can anyone please help me what I did wrong on my EventHandler for some reason I can't open the Display Conformation box?

Tags: javascript

This is the code:

```
<form NAME = "winform">
<p>
<input TYPE = "button" VALUE = "Display An Alert" 
onClick = "window.alert('This is a test alert');">
</p>

<p>
<input TYPE = "button" VALUE = "Display a confirmation" 
onClick "temp = window.confirm = ('Would you like to confirm?'); window.status = (temp)?        'confirm:true' : 'confirm:false';">
</p>

<p>
<input TYPE = "button" VALUE = "Display a prompt" 
onClick="var temp = window.prompt('Enter some text:','This is the default value');  window.status=temp;">
</p>
```

I got the alert and prompt displayed except for this one. I tried using Chrome and IE with their stupid developer closed they have its nearly impossible to tell if I done my skills correctly so now I'm here asking for help whether I've done it correctly.

Comment: The 90's called and want their UPPERCASE ATTRIBUTES back. Aside from that, the error is in `window.confirm = ...`. You have one too many assignments; the function isn't called.

Comment: Actually I'm only doing one at a time since I'm learning JavaScript I'm not in that part of the tutorial book in the book it showed the confirmation popping.  http://tinypic.com/r/1sxh6w/5

Comment: I don't know what that screenshot is supposed to facilitate. Have you removed the superfluous ` = ` and retried the script?

Comment: I actually did and the confirmation isn't showing up

Comment: ...and yet it should. Whatever you've tried, could you please update your question with it?

Answer (score 2):

Well your HTML looks really bad... but i think the problem is in the onclick:

`onClick "temp = window.confirm = ('Would you like to confirm?'); window.status = (temp)?        'confirm:true' : 'confirm:false';"`

needs to be something like this:

`onClick="temp = window.confirm('Would you like to confirm?'); window.status = (temp)?        'confirm:true' : 'confirm:false';"`

also make sure `temp` is declared in the correct scope (with `var temp`)

Comment: Um here's my image I'm doing a single line function I'm not trying to connect those two its click an alert pops up the first and third works not the second. http://i44.tinypic.com/1sxh6w.jpg

Comment: Here are my example I wish I would have include them in. http://i43.tinypic.com/2q16h49.png (1) http://i42.tinypic.com/24njn9f.png (2)  OS: Window7